# Updating Android Studio 3.2 and show gradle project sync failed

Tags: java, android

Default file proguard-android.txt should not be specified in this module. It can be specified in the base module instead.
what can I do with that to solve this error.

Comment: your proguard file should be in root app folder, make sure it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line in build.gradle(Module: feature):

"//proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'"